# View package content created with productbuild

Tags: macos, productbuild

I created a pkg file with the *productbuild* utility and I'd like to see its content. How can I do that?

I'm under *MacOS 10.9.5*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extract your package into temporary directory with [pkgutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgutil.1.html).

```
pkgutil --expand pkg-path dir-path

Expand the flat package at pkg-path into a new directory specified by dir-path.
```

There is also very good third party tool called [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com), by CharlesSoft. You can view the contents of the package without extracting it.

**Update**

Inside `pkg` archive (which is a `xar` archive) you may encounter following files:

- **Bom**:         Mac OS X bill of materials (BOM) file

> The Mac OS X Installer uses a file system "bill of materials" to determine which files to install, remove, or upgrade. A bill of materials, bom, contains all the files within a directory, along with some information about each file. File information includes: the file's UNIX permissions, its owner and group, its size, its time of last modification, and so on.
>   Also included are a checksum of each file and information about hard links. [[man bom](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/bom.5.html)]

You may list the contents of `bom` file with [lsbom](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsbom.8.html) command. And create the file with [mkbom](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mkbom.8.html).

- **PackageInfo**: XML  document text

This `xml` file contains general information about the package.

- **Payload**:     gzip compressed data, from Unix

This is a gziped `cpio` archive. You may extract its contents to current directory with `tar` command:

```
$ tar -xf Payload
```

Or extract to specified directory `dir-path`:

```
$ tar -C dir-path -xf Payload
```

Optionally you may only list the contents of the `Payload` archive with:

```
$ tar -tf Payload
```

You should be able to recreate the archive from `dir-path` with:

```
$ tar --format cpio -czf Payload dir-path
```

Comment: When I extract it I have folder com.mydomain.mypackage.pkg containing three files: Bom, PackInfo and Payload. How do I extrack the content of Payload?

Comment: Your answer is impressive! Thanks ;-)